# freemarker issue Undeclared throwable:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: struts2, freemarker

We are facing a problem in our web application that is using FreeMarker template file for constructing HTML. Everything works fine but at a certain point the freemarker template custom file starts to cause the below Exception, we are unable to determine the cause of the error because it appears very rarely, but once it appears then it continue to appear until we redeploy our web application.

So since redeploy of the application solves the error, then the cause might be that the .ftl file definition is being corrupted in the cache.

we are using `template_update_delay=60000` to delay reload of template on every call.

we are using freemarker2.3.16.jar

any help is appreciated

```
Undeclared throwable:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at 
freemarker.ext.jsp.PageContextFactory.getCurrentPageContext(PageContextFactory.java:54) at 
freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel.getWriter(TagTransformModel.java:99) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:286) at 
freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:299) at 
freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210) at 
freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190) at 
freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237) at 
org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerResult.doExecute(FreemarkerResult.java:201) at 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
com.path.lib.common.interceptor.PathSessionInterceptor.intercept(PathSessionInterceptor.java:72) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at 
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) at 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511) at 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) at 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:88) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74) at 
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129) at 
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74) at 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:82) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:256) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:117) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:95) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:79) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:268) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:121) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254) at 
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at 
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at 
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513) at 
weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254) at 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256) at 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
freemarker.ext.jsp.FreeMarkerPageContext.(FreeMarkerPageContext.java:159) at 
freemarker.ext.jsp.FreeMarkerPageContext21.(FreeMarkerPageContext21.java:36) at 
freemarker.ext.jsp.FreeMarkerPageContext21.create(FreeMarkerPageContext21.java:40) ... 100 more
```

Comment: It's unlikely caching is so broken that it makes for a repeatable reflection error. Define "a certain point". It looks more like data or an object expected to be there isn't.

Comment: If you look at the stack trace it says that `setAttribute(CONFIG, servlet.getServletConfig());` has thrown NPE. That's only possible if `servlet` is `null`, which is only possible if `ServletContextHashModel.servlet` is `null`, which is only possible if something calls the deprecated `ServletContextHashModel(ServletContext, ObjectWrapper)` constructor. FreeMarker doesn't call it I believe. (Are you sure about the version number?) Very strange. And why are the method names missing from the first two cause trace lines?

Comment: And according what I said, it has nothing to do with FTL cache... It's in the Servlet/JSP integration.

Comment: thanks @ddekany yes the freemarker version is 2.3.16, yes we noticed from our investigation that servlet comes as null, but did not discover the reason.  first two lines are as follows (we have a struts2 interceptor class that call the method in the struts2 TreeMenuAction):[23/09/2014 15:53:52] com.path.lib.common.interceptor.PathSessionInterceptor.intercept(PathSessionInterceptor.java:80)
 [ERROR]: PathSessionInterceptor action class is com.path.actions.common.menu.TreeMenuAction

Comment: What could be the Servlet/JSP integration Problem?

Comment: more over in our ftl we have regular expression matcher as follows: `<#assign specialChars=idMenuVar?matches('.*[%!@#$%^&*(){}<>=\\[\\]/\\\\\'\"].*')/>` and then we have 3 nested if where last one is `<#if specialChars> ... <#else> ...</#if>`. And seems the issue comes from this if because the tags before this condition are constructed

Comment: Dear Dave, by "certain point" i mean when redirecting to ftl file in our web application, but it is not something appearing always but suddenly start to appear, no specific criteria.

Comment: Why do you think that the issue is related to the `if`-s? From the nature of the error it doesn't look related. The thing that should be investigated here is if how that `null` gets into the `servet` field.

Comment: Why it is happening with this ftl file only, although we have a lot of struts2 ftl files inside the application that do not cause any problem. you are right need to investigate how null is set into servlet but this is not appearing always it is rare issue and not possible to debug.